# Unable to add new line in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am creating a view where the user can enter text like a notepad and when user presses ENTER, the cursor will go to the next line. I have tried many configurations with EditText by exploring inputType, imeOptions maxLines etc. with no luck.

The text always stays in a single line. If the line length is more than the view, it simply grows to the right.

Is there a way to make sure the EditText

1. Accepts new lines and display text with line breaks?
2. Wraps to the width of the container

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_box">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/act_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text= "April 12, 2015 2:45 PM"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:textColor="?attr/attrColorNewEntryChangedDate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <View
            android:id="@+id/act_change_date_border"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?attr/attrColorBorder"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:imeOptions="actionNone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            

           />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make your edit text wrap_content.

Answer (score -2):

you can try this

```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:maxLines="3"
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.